# Replace html link with a server output using JQuery in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am new to JQuery and trying to learn it, one of which is to replace any link (say "Current Server Time") with a particular output, in this case - the current time, on clicking over it.

Here is my html code:

```
<div id="servertime">
    <a href="#" id="timelink">Current Server Time</a>
</div>
```

In a javascript file, I am doing this:

```
$("#timelink").click(showServerTime);

var showServerTime = function () {

        var $a = $(this);

        var options = {
            url: "/Home/GetServerTime",
            type: "post",
            dataType: "string"
        }

        $.ajax(options).done(function (data) {
            var $target = $a;
            var $newHtml = $(data);
            $target.replaceWith($newHtml);
        });
        return false;
        };
```

And finally here is my C# function:

```
public string GetServerTime()
        {
            return DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        }
```

All these three pieces of code are in separate file of their own. On clicking the link there is absolutely no response. Where am I going wrong here? Is this the correct approach?

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint in your c# function to see if the call to the server is working? Also are you getting any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: The C# function is getting called, but the link is not changing to the return value.

Comment: Are you sure $a (and then $target) contain the link which you are expecting to replace? Have you put a breakpoint in your script and inspected the contents of this variable?

Comment: @Sam Change `type` to `GET` and `dataType` to `text`.

Comment: @Calvedos using $("#timelink") should give me  '<a href="#" id="timelink">Current Server Time</a>', which i can replace with the data (current time returned by c# function) and display as text. Have I understood this correctly?

Comment: @wizkid Ok, I will try that. Do I need to set 'data' field as well in the options variable?

Comment: @Sam No. It's not required.

Comment: Made a couple of changes:

1) Changed dataType: string to dataType: text as suggested by @wizkid
2) Wrote this: $a.replaceWith(data); (data is actually my text to be printed out) to replace instead of using JQuery object $(data) which was implied by above code.

Got it working finally. Thanks a lot guys!